# Periodicity of the cohomology of $\mathbb RP^\infty$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I want to prove that there is an isomorphism
$$H^*(\Sigma^{2^j}\mathbb RP^b/\mathbb RP^a:\mathbb Z/2)\cong H^*(\mathbb RP^{b+2^j}/\mathbb RP^{a+2^j}:\mathbb Z/2)$$
compatible with the Steenrod operations for any natural numbers $a, b$, and $j$ with $a\leq b$ and $2^j\geq b-a$.

I know that I have to use the equality
$$\binom{n+2^j}{k}=\binom{n}{k}\mod 2$$
for $2^j>k$ but I don't know how to apply it in this case. Any hint?

*My attempt:*

Both spaces are path connected, so they both have the $0$-th cohomology isormorphic to $\mathbb Z/2$. Therefore, sending generator to generator, we can construct an isomorphism on the 0-th cohomology. By composing suspensions isomorphisms, we have isomorphisms on reduced cohomology
$$\sigma^{2^j}:\widetilde{H}^*(\mathbb RP^b/\mathbb RP^a:\mathbb Z/2)\to \widetilde{H}^{*+2^j}(\Sigma^{2^j}\mathbb RP^b/\mathbb RP^a:\mathbb Z/2) $$
Moreover, there are also isomorphisms
$$\widetilde{H}^*(\mathbb RP^b/\mathbb RP^a:\mathbb Z/2)\to \widetilde{H}^{*+2^j}(\mathbb RP^{b+2^j}/\mathbb RP^{a+2^j}:\mathbb Z/2)$$
Therefore, we can construct the isomorphism
$$\phi:H^*(\Sigma^{2j}\mathbb RP^b/\mathbb RP^a:\mathbb Z/2)\to H^*(\mathbb RP^{b+2^j}/\mathbb RP^{a+2^j}:\mathbb Z/2)$$
at least on a cohomology groups level.

We want to find which conditions on the parameters $a,b,j$ let $\phi$ be compatible with the Steenrod operations. We have that $\phi$ is compatible with $Sq$ if the diagram 
[image]
commutes. Since $\phi$ is an isomorphism at each degree, we just need to check this on the generators. For $x$ algebra generator of $H^*(\mathbb RP^\infty)$,

$$Sq(x^n)=(Sq(x))^n=(x^2+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^{n+k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+2^j}{k}x^{n+k}$$
is it the right direction?

Comment: You are taking coefficients over $\mathbb{Z}/2$, are you sure the $0$-degree cohomology is $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: You are right. Fixed it

Comment: Also in your solutions you do not use the fact that $ 2^j\geq b-a $. How come?

Comment: It's not a solution yet, how should I use that? for the cup product structure?

Comment: I think it is mostly there to ensure that $a+2^{j}\geq b$ and hence we have, as you indicate in the title, periodicity phenomena.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for hints, so here are some: if $x$ is the algebra generator of $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^\infty; \mathbb{F}_2)$, then $\text{Sq}(x)=x+x^2$, where Sq is the total Steenrod square, $\text{Sq} = \sum \text{Sq}^i$. The operator Sq is an algebra map.

Edit: further hints: the mod 2 cohomology groups of the real projective spaces are generated (as vector spaces) by the powers of $x$, and the equation $\text{Sq}(x^n) = (\text{Sq}(x))^n$ lets you compute the action of the Steenrod operations on $x^n$. If you expand the right side of this, you will see binomial coefficients...

Comment: I put an attempt in the question but I still don't know how to use your hints. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @LelloPold Okay, I've elaborated.

Comment: Since $x$ is of degree $1$ isnt it true that $\text{Sq}(x)=x+x^2$ and not $\text{Sq}(x)=1+x$ ?

Comment: Yes, you're right, fixed, thank you.

Comment: Is the cohomology  of the suspension also generated by the power of $x$?

Comment: @LelloPold I would say that it is generated by the suspension of the power of x, and since the Steenrod operations are stable, they commute with the suspension operator.

Comment: last thing: why also the cohomology groups of the quotient $\mathbb RP^b/\mathbb RP^a$ are generated by powers of $x$?

Comment: In the dimensions you care about, the cohomology of $\mathbb{R}P^b$ is isomorphic to that of $\mathbb{R}P^b/\mathbb{R}P^a$.